# Target Specific navigation links with nth child of nth child in css - Shopify

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm working on this Shopify site - https://kindlehouse.co.uk/ - and trying to highlight key items in their navigation as bold using CSS. I'm struggling to get the right syntax to be able to select a top tier item them subsequent item inside of that part of the navigation.

Due to the setup of Shopify, I can't add classes or other ways to target specific menu items unfortunately so I need an alternative.

I can successfully target top level items with:

```
ul.site-nav > li:nth-child(1) > a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the second tier of the first navigation item using:

```
ul.site-nav__dropdown > li:nth-child(1) > a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

However, I can't seem to get the right syntax to be able to choose a first tier item and then a second tier item from that list.

I have tried css such as this:

```
ul.site-nav > li:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I have seen you can nest nth child rules to target groups within groups but can't seem to get it working for this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your html too, preferably edit your question and use the snippet button to create a [mcve].  See [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)